# Android pager views not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using android support library for ViewPager(App will support 2.2 and above).
The pager views has Fragements, my fragments contain lists, text on that list is not visible,  images are visible though.
On inner screens where I am using activity with lists the text is visible, so i think problem is only with Fragments.
This is happening only for 2.2 and 2.3, devices above 3.0 show text properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by building app on android 2.3.3 instead of 4.1 
The text issues are solved, though some functionality such as Spinner dropDown mode is not avaliable now.